# Is it possible to upgrade (not clean install) Win 7 from safe mode/cd boot

Tags: windows-7, reinstall

I can't load my win 7, there are a lot of DCOM-related errors in e vent log.
I want to repair my installation and install win 7 to the same drive/directory without wiping the disk.
But I can't choose upgrade option when I boot from CD/Win 7 safe mode, and I can't boot in the normal mode. Is it ossible to avid clean reinstall in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. You cannot boot from CD?
If you have a Windows 7 Disk you can F12 > Boot from CD > Choose Language > and then on the CD You'll see "INSTALL NOW" but instead of clicking that, look lower, you will see "Repair your computer" underneath "What to know before installing Windows". Clicking this will allow you to access repair tools to fix corrupted system files.

This is a link that does it, but it provides a lot of different options to perform a system repair: http://mintywhite.com/windows-7/7maintenance/windows-wont-load-system-repair-disc-fix-pc/

Comment: I run all ths repair tools, but they tell me that no files are corrupted.